# StatusCallBack for iOS SDK

Tags: ios, twilio

I'm using the iOS client SDK for VoIP, and need to know when a caller has accepted, rejected or ignored an incoming call. Everything I've read suggests using StatusCallBack, but this seems to be available only in the REST API, not the iOS client API. How can I do this in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Michael, Megan from Twilio here.

Unfortunately, at this time it's not possible to do this directly with the [iOS SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios). There is a feature request in place.

In the meantime, to set up call progress, you'll need to bypass the iOS TCDevice connect method, and instead have your iOS code make a request to your server to set up both legs of the call through the Twilio [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter-request-parameters), so that it can enable the call progress events. Your server needs to then communicate the events back to your iOS code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Megan - thanks for your fast reply. After initiating a call, I am receiving a connectionDidConnect event, with state = TCConnectionStateConnected , even before the receiving user taps accept or ignore. (Even if they never even respond to the call.) I'm guessing that's the way it works, and would require the same workaround you mentioned?

Comment: Indeed. The behavior you see regarding TCConnection is expected. A TCConnection is either incoming or outgoing. You do not create a TCConnection directly; an outgoing connection is created by calling the [TCDevice connect:delegate:] method. Incoming connections are created internally by TCDevice and handed to the registered TCDeviceDelegate via [TCDeviceDelegate device:didReceiveIncomingConnection:]. That workaround still applies.